# how to fix string must be provide to a text widget?

Tags: flutter, android-studio, sharedpreferences

How to fix this problem `this string cannot be provided in the text widget.`
How can I solve this? My code:
[code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rf5EF.jpg)

Comment: Pls enter your code directly to the question :)

Comment: pls hellp me !!!

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is that `fullName` is of type `String?` instead of `String`. That means you need to ensure it is not null.

Either by enforcing a null check

```dart
Text(fullName!)
```

or by providing a fallback value

```dart
Text(fullName ?? 'fallback')
```

or by only showing the text if fullName is not null like

```dart
if (fullName != null)
  Text(fullName)
```

Comment: if i change to Text(fullName ?? 'fallback')
i got The following ArgumentError was thrown building ProfilePages(dirty, state: _ProfilePagesState#fb74c):
Invalid argument(s)

The relevant error-causing widget was
ProfilePages
lib\main_page.dart:18
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      _StringBase.+ (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:279:43)
#1      _ProfilePagesState.build

Answer (score 2):

Because your fullName text canbe null, try handle fullName null case:

```
Text(
      fullName ?? '',
      style: boldTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
    )
```

Comment: if i change to
Text(
      fullName ?? '',
      style: boldTextStyle.copyWith(fontSize: 18),
    )

output : 
Exception has occurred.
ArgumentError (Invalid argument(s))

Comment: can you provide full code ? I 'll check it

Comment: You can copy paste to your question, then select all code section , press Ctrl+K